# on expect: need to spawn a python script that fetches a string and send it back

Tags: bash, expect

The first script is basically an external lib that I don't want to tamper with.

I already tried the following:

```
set timeout 100
spawn python long-running-script-with-prompt.py

expect "Type the 6 digit code here:" {
   set CODE [python fetch-code.py]
   send "$CODE\n"
}
```

This however just breaks the first script, similar to just canceling. Is the problem in the expect script?

Comment: Why bother with an expect script? You could probably just pipe it.

Comment: I suggest use a function in python script and read argument from your python script .

Comment: In expect (a Tcl extension), you need the [`exec` command](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) to capture the stdout of an external command